# Using build generated by Xcode as iOS Simulator Build for Facebook Review

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

Is it possible to use the .app generated by Xcode for Facebook Review instead of compile it outside Xcode with 'xcodebuild' command?

Thank you